# Specify RGB or HEX line colours within R plot

Tags: r

I have created a plot and I am adding lines to the plot. I want the line colour to follow a specific RGB value but for the life of me I cant seem to get it to work.

I have been trying the code below to no avail!

```
lines(dataframe$v1,dataframe$v2,col=rgb(192,0,0))
```

How can you do it in either RGB or HEX?

Thanks

Comment: Go to `?par` and scroll down to 'Color Specifications` to see all the options.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the red, green, and blue values are scaled to fall within the interval [0,1], you'll want to supply a value (typically `255`) to the `maxColorValue` argument:

```
myRed <- rgb(192,0,0, maxColorValue=255)
myRed
# [1] "#C00000"
plot(rnorm(250), pch=16, col=myRed)
```

[image]

Comment: ...and for the second part of the question about how to use hex, just use the code, `...,col="#C00000")`